# Calculated column based on another calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

In a sharepoint list I have one Number column named "DAYS" and onther calculated column named "TAKEN" with the formula (=DATEDIF[StartDate],[EndDate],"d")).
I need to substract from "DAYS" the result from the calculated column "TAKEN" but it gives me an error.

``` =[DAYS]-DATEDIF([StartDate];[EndDate];"d") ``

I bet is really simple but driving me crazy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be the semicolons. You use semicolons or commas depending on cultural settings.

Try:

```
  =[DAYS]-DATEDIF([StartDate];[EndDate];"d")
```

Or:

```
  =[DAYS]-DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"d")
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your answer! Apparently the deal was the data in days was being considered text... but yes in my country we have to use semi colon and works fine.